# How to mock a custom hook that fetches data with SWR in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress

I have this component that uses a custom hook called `useBuildingAPI` which internally uses the SWR hook to fetch data, and I want to create component testing for it, however I found issues with importing the custom hook inside my component testing file:

**Building Details Form:**

```
"use client"

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"

import { Error as BuildingDetailsError } from "../shared/components/feedback/Error"
import Form from "./components/Form"
import { LoadingSkeleton } from "./components/Loading"
import { useBuildingAPI } from "./hooks/api/useBuildingAPI"
import styles from "./style.module.css"
import { AddressInfo } from "./types"

export const BuildingDetailsForm = (props: AddressInfo) => {
  const addressDetails = props

  const { isLoading, data, error } = useBuildingAPI(addressDetails)
  const path = usePathname()

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingSkeleton />
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <BuildingDetailsError
        message='Wir können unsere Server nicht verbinden, bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Verbindung.'
        buttonText='versuchen Sie es erneut'
        redirectUrl={path}
      />
    )
  }

  if (!data) {
    return (
      <BuildingDetailsError
        message='Dieses Gebäude dient nicht zum Wohnen. Wir zeigen Daten zu Wohngebäuden an.'
        buttonText='versuchen Sie es erneut'
        redirectUrl={"/"}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles["container"]}>
      <Form data={data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This component uses a custom for data fetching `useBuildingAPI`:

```
import { fetcher } from "@/utils/fetcher"
import useSWR from "swr"

import { getURL } from "../../api/getURL"
import { AddressInfo, BuildingAPIResponseData } from "../../types"
import { findBuilding, formatData } from "../../utils"

export const useBuildingAPI = (addressDetails: AddressInfo) => {
  let formattedData: BuildingAPIResponseData | undefined

  const url = getURL(addressDetails)

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(url, fetcher)

  if (data) {
    const buildingWithLivingFunction = findBuilding(data, "hasLivingFunction", true) as BuildingAPIResponseData

    if (buildingWithLivingFunction) {
      formattedData = formatData(buildingWithLivingFunction) as BuildingAPIResponseData
    }
  }

  return {
    data: formattedData,
    error,
    isLoading,
  }
}
```

I just started importing the custom hook `useBuildingAPI` in my test:

```
import { useBuildingAPI } from "./hooks/api/useBuildingAPI"

describe("", () => {
  const zipCode = "63110"
  const city = "Rodgau"
  const street = "Liebigstraße"
  const houseNumber = "2"

  const address = {
    city,
    street,
    zipCode,
    houseNumber,
  }
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useBuildingAPI(address)
})
```

This is the issue:

[image]